# How can I open a google doc file with Google Drive on Android

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am using the Google Drive List API on an own Android app and listing the files stored on Google Drive. When I select a Google Doc file on my own App I want to open it with the official Google Drive Android-App, how can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: is this Google Drive Android-App created by you?

Comment: Have you looked into sending an 'Intent' from your app. This should trigger Google Drive.

Comment: What intent? with what parameters? where is the docu?

Answer (score 1):

If you open the file URL in Android, it should ask you if you want to use the Google Doc app or the web browser.

The URL is typically what you'll get from the Doc List, something like:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/_Doc_list_resource_id_/edit

Comment: I tried with the "alternateLink" (should be the link for opening with googledocs.
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.putExtra("accountName", "account@gmail.com");
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, mimeType);
activity.startActivity(intent); 
Google Docs opens, but then I get a Dialog unable to open, check your internet connecition or you may not have permission for this file. I use the drive scope, and the account used to list the file is the same than the one used in the google Drive app, so I do not understand about what permission it is talking about.